# How do I get binary value as an integer in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
b = 15
a = bin(b)      # I want return as an integer not string
print(a, type(a))  # output is string, actually I want is integer

# output - 0b1111 <class 'str'>
```

So, I want to get bin() function return as an integer

Comment: The easiest way is to parse this binary as an int `int(a[2:])`

Comment: What integer are you expecting to be returned?  `15` is already being stored as a binary number internally, it's only being converted to decimal for display.

Answer (score 1):

The int function is used to convert to the integer. We need to pass the number and its base to convert it into an integer (since, the base for binary values is 2).

```
a = int('101',2)

print(a)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

If you question is about converting for example 5 into bin in python, the bin function actually gives `0b101` as the result. So the simple trick to get `101` as an int is

```py
intnum=int(bin(number)[2:])
```

Comment: But 101 is one hundred and one, the decimal number.

Comment: @kaya3, But that's what the question is about right?